# Ordinary Differential Equation Question

Tags: differential-equations

I was wondering whether someone might be able to point me in the right direction for this ODE that I am trying to solve?

It is:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{x}{s}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{u}{x}$$

with $s$ some constant.

I have tried separating the variables but that did not work...

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the Mathematics forum, this forum is for the program *Mathematica*, which can solve that problem readily with the function `DSolve`.

Comment: Either `DSolve` or http://math.stackexchange.com.  (This site is for the technical software *Mathematica* -- is that what you're asking about?)

Comment: ah right - thank you, my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

This is a so called first order differential equation, in general not solvable via separation of variables. You have to solve the homogenous equation an then determine a specific solution.
For more info see [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html)

I forgot to mention that *Mathematica* (surely) solves this equation:

```
DSolve[u'[x] + u[x]/x == x/s - 1/2, u[x], x]
```

Comment: The solution is {u[x] -> -(x/4) + x^2/(3 s) + C[1]/x}